# Достигнутое достижение

Tags: грамотная-речь, словосочетания

Возможно ли употребление словосочетания "достигнутое достижение"?

Comment: Мне кажется, это слишком широкий, слишком общий вопрос. В такой формулировке напрашивается ответ - да, возможно. Если появятся подробности, то ответ может измениться.

Answer (score 1):

Ну вестимо дело, нет. Масло масляное. Тавтологией называется.

Как авторский приём, только изрядно стилистически мотивированный, можно

*дела делать, слоны слонять* (Лесков), *разговоры разговаривать* (Устинова).

---

> Всякий скажет, что «старый старик» или «молодой юноша» — тавтология,
>   такая же как «водянистая вода», «сладкий сахар» или «холодный лёд». А
>   вот «мужественный мужчина» уже не тавтология, ведь мужчина может быть
>   трусливым, а мужественной может быть и женщина, и даже девочка. Просто
>   слово «мужественный» когда-то потеряло своё старинное значение
>   «подобный мужчине» и приобрело новое — «храбрый». А вот «мужеподобный
>   мужчина» — уже тавтология.